# Simplifying double einsum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, numpy-einsum

I'm trying to use `numpy.einsum` to simplify a loop I have in my code.

Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
k = 100 
m = 50
n = 10
A = np.arange(k*m*n).reshape(k, m, n)
B = np.arange(m*m).reshape(m, m)

T = np.zeros((n, n)) 
for ind in xrange(k):
    T += np.dot(A[ind,:,:].T, np.dot(B, A[ind,:,:]))
```

I'm trying to use `numpy.einsum` as an alternative to this loop:

```
Tp = np.einsum('nij,njk->ik', np.einsum('nij,jk->nik', A.transpose(0,2,1), B), A)
print np.allclose(T, Tp)
```

Is it possible to use a single `numpy.einsum` instead of two?

Comment: on my computer, `print (np.allclose(T, Tp))` is false ??.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really smart approaches you got in the other answer. I would like to add [`numpy.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) based approach into the mix that also uses some `reshaping`. Here's one way to do so -

```
k,m,n = A.shape
((A.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,m).dot(B.T)).reshape(n,-1)).dot(A.reshape(-1,n)).T
```

Runtime tests -

This section compares all the approaches listed in the [`other answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33400806/3293881) and `numpy.dot` based one listed earlier in this post.

```
In [130]: k = 100 
     ...: m = 50
     ...: n = 10
     ...: A = np.arange(k*m*n).reshape(k, m, n)
     ...: B = np.arange(m*m).reshape(m, m)
     ...: 

In [131]: %timeit np.einsum('nij,njk->ik', np.einsum('nij,jk->nik', A.transpose(0,2,1), B), A)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop

In [132]: %timeit np.einsum('nij, il, kln ->jk', A, B, A.T)
10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop

In [133]: %timeit np.tensordot(A, np.tensordot(A, B, axes=(1, 1)), axes=((0, 1), (0, 2)))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.22 ms per loop

In [134]: %timeit ((A.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,m).dot(B.T)).reshape(n,-1)).dot(A.reshape(-1,n)).T
100 loops, best of 3: 5.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Internally, I believe, `tensordot` uses same sort of `transpose` and `reshape` as you do.  Timings are close enough.

Comment: @hpaulj Hmm it might. From my benchmarks, I always found `np.dot` to be tad-faster than `np.tensordot`, so that might be the function call overhead. In this case, there are numerous ways to reshape and transpose and after many trials I found out the listed one to be the most optimized. Also, `np.dot` gives me more control, so I thought this could be tried here :)

Answer (score 4):

On my PC your timing would be:

```
np.einsum('nij,njk->ik', np.einsum('nij,jk->nik', A.transpose(0,2,1), B), A)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 4.55 ms per loop
```

You can achieve that with:

```
T2 = np.einsum('nij, il, kln ->jk', A, B, A.T)
#  10 loops, best of 3: 51.9 ms per loop
```

or using a double `np.tensordot()`:

```
T3 = np.tensordot(A, np.tensordot(A, B, axes=(1, 1)), axes=((0, 1), (0, 2)))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.73 ms per loop
```

My conclusion is that you are getting a **better performance** doing this operation **in two steps**. This is probably due to the bigger strides that happen when the operation is performed at once, possibly causing more cache losses.